# Async array map - can we use map instead of a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await

Given this JavaScript snipped (not TypeScript!). How can we use map instead of a loop?

```
import { serialize } from 'next-mdx-remote/serialize'
...
const helperArray = []
for (const element of arrayOfObjects) {
  helperArray.push({ ...element, description: await serialize(element.description)})
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could try [`const helperArray = await Promise.all(arrayOfObjects.map(async (`…`) =>`…`))`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answers. I'll check the information. Probably this answers my question already. Have to think a little bit.

Comment: This solution uses two array map methods, but it should work out fine, as long as you use it in an async function:

    const promiseArray = arrayOfObjects.map((element) => {
        return serialize(element.description)
    })
    
    await Promise.allSettled(promiseArray)
    
    const resultArray = arrayOfObjects.map((element, index) => {
        return { ...element, description: promiseArray[index]}
    })

Comment: Someone closed the question right before I could answer. Sorry for the lousy formatting.